# Every possible value of N (rectangle exercise)

Tags: geometry

If you need to:

Find every value of number N, where N is the number of right triangles that divide rectangle.

What are steps to find that number N ?

Comment: What does "to divide a rectangle by a right triangle" mean?

Comment: Well if the N is 2, you can divide rectangle into 2 90-degrees triangles.

Comment: Well, in that case, $N$ can be any positive integer

Comment: I can use two 90-degree triangles to form a rectangle, and I can divide a given rectangle into _any number of smaller rectangles_, so I don't understand the question, I'm afraid

Comment: That's the same thing I was thinking of, but I don't know am I correct so I asked it here

Comment: You may want to add the restriction that you are not looking for nested triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
 What does this tell you?

> You can take a rectangle and divide it into an even number of right triangles following the strategy described in the image (i.e. dividing every rectangle in smaller rectangles and these in right triangles with the diagonal).

---

> Now, how to obtain an odd number of right triangles? Easy: Take one of the right triangles and divide it into two further right triangles with the altitude. Hence $N$ can take any value in $\mathbb Z^+\setminus\{1\}$

Here's how you can achieve an odd number of triangles

[image]

Comment: Is N any number in Z+ or any even number in Z+?

Comment: $N$ can be odd or even

Comment: Is N on the third picture (green one) equal to 3 or 6 ?(We have 6 triangles on third picture)

Comment: In the third picture $N=6$

Comment: Can N be equal to 3 ?

Comment: See the edit; BTW I've just noticed that $N=1$ cannot be achived